# Valid Windows Azure Active Directory redirect Uris

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

From the help text

> Redirect URIs
>
> The URI to which Windows Azure AD will redirect in response to an
>   OAuth 2.0 request. The value does not need to be a physical endpoint,
>   but must be a valid URI. Windows Azure AD will also check that the
>   redirect URI your application supplies in the OAuth 2.0 request
>   matches one of these registered values.

it stats that it do not need to be a physical endpoint but I have had no luck entering a valid urn endpoint

tried urn:myname:application

What are valid uris if its not urns and not a physical endpoint. ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's probably a documentation error.  The RFC defines it as an Endpoint Uri (I interpret this to mean URL).  It also suggests using TLS for the Endpoint Uri, which wouldn't make sense for a URN.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

Comment: But it makes perfect sense that a urn should be allowed for client applications that cant be redirected.

Comment: Ok, for client apps the physical endpoint does not have to exist & any URI should work.  Oddly, it does seem to be enforcing syntax rules on the URI.  I was just experimenting with it & here's what I found.

These work:
urn://myname
urn://myname:123

The trick seems to be the "//" in the uri **and** if you have a ":" in the uri, it want's to be able to convert the text after the ":" to a numeric value for it to be acceptable.  After further review, this does appear to contradict the docs because your original uri should work (IMO).

Comment: Anyway, give this a try and see if it works.  If so, I'll revise/improve my answer.  Although, I think there's still room for clarification on what constitutes a valid URI in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Also had problems with this when developing a native app. 
I found that the format:  https://www.google.com wont work but https://google.com will.